# Error trace of compiling custom app while building Android ROM

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, trace

I'm seeing the following errors when I try to build an android lollipop ROM with a dummy app called "ClubInternetLives".

```
target Dex: SoundRecorder
target Dex: CaptivePortalLogin
target Dex: CertInstaller
target Java: ClubInternetLives (out/target/common/obj/APPS/ClubInternetLives_intermediates/classes)
target Dex: DownloadProviderUi
target Dex: HTMLViewer
packages/apps/ClubInternetLives/app/src/androidTest/java/clubinternetlives/androidstudio/com/clubinternetlives/ApplicationTest.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
import android.test.ApplicationTestCase;
                   ^
  symbol:   class ApplicationTestCase
  location: package android.test
packages/apps/ClubInternetLives/app/src/androidTest/java/clubinternetlives/androidstudio/com/clubinternetlives/ApplicationTest.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
public class ApplicationTest extends ApplicationTestCase {
                                     ^
  symbol: class ApplicationTestCase
packages/apps/ClubInternetLives/app/src/main/java/clubinternetlives/androidstudio/com/clubinternetlives/MainActivity.java:4: error: package android.support.design.widget does not exist
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
                                    ^
packages/apps/ClubInternetLives/app/src/main/java/clubinternetlives/androidstudio/com/clubinternetlives/MainActivity.java:5: error: package android.support.design.widget does not exist
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
                                    ^
packages/apps/ClubInternetLives/app/src/main/java/clubinternetlives/androidstudio/com/clubinternetlives/MainActivity.java:6: error: package android.support.v7.app does not exist
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
                             ^
packages/apps/ClubInternetLives/app/src/main/java/clubinternetlives/androidstudio/com/clubinternetlives/MainActivity.java:7: error: package android.support.v7.widget does not exist
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
                                ^
packages/apps/ClubInternetLives/app/src/main/java/clubinternetlives/androidstudio/com/clubinternetlives/MainActivity.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
                                  ^
  symbol: class AppCompatActivity
packages/apps/ClubInternetLives/app/src/test/java/clubinternetlives/androidstudio/com/clubinternetlives/ExampleUnitTest.java:3: error: package org.junit does not exist
import org.junit.Test;
                ^
packages/apps/ClubInternetLives/app/src/test/java/clubinternetlives/androidstudio/com/clubinternetlives/ExampleUnitTest.java:5: error: package org.junit does not exist
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
                       ^
packages/apps/ClubInternetLives/app/src/test/java/clubinternetlives/androidstudio/com/clubinternetlives/ExampleUnitTest.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
    @Test
     ^
  symbol:   class Test
  location: class ExampleUnitTest
target Dex: KeyChain
packages/apps/ClubInternetLives/app/src/main/java/clubinternetlives/androidstudio/com/clubinternetlives/MainActivity.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ^
  symbol:   variable super
  location: class MainActivity
packages/apps/ClubInternetLives/app/src/main/java/clubinternetlives/androidstudio/com/clubinternetlives/MainActivity.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ^
  symbol:   method setContentView(int)
  location: class MainActivity
packages/apps/ClubInternetLives/app/src/main/java/clubinternetlives/androidstudio/com/clubinternetlives/MainActivity.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        ^
  symbol:   class Toolbar
  location: class MainActivity
packages/apps/ClubInternetLives/app/src/main/java/clubinternetlives/androidstudio/com/clubinternetlives/MainActivity.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
                           ^
  symbol:   class Toolbar
  location: class MainActivity
packages/apps/ClubInternetLives/app/src/main/java/clubinternetlives/androidstudio/com/clubinternetlives/MainActivity.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
                                    ^
  symbol:   method findViewById(int)
  location: class MainActivity
packages/apps/ClubInternetLives/app/src/main/java/clubinternetlives/androidstudio/com/clubinternetlives/MainActivity.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        ^
  symbol:   class FloatingActionButton
  location: class MainActivity
packages/apps/ClubInternetLives/app/src/main/java/clubinternetlives/androidstudio/com/clubinternetlives/MainActivity.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
                                    ^
  symbol:   class FloatingActionButton
  location: class MainActivity
packages/apps/ClubInternetLives/app/src/main/java/clubinternetlives/androidstudio/com/clubinternetlives/MainActivity.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
                                                          ^
  symbol:   method findViewById(int)
  location: class MainActivity
Proguard: out/target/common/obj/APPS/LiveWallpapers_intermediates/proguard.classes.jar
packages/apps/ClubInternetLives/app/src/main/java/clubinternetlives/androidstudio/com/clubinternetlives/MainActivity.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                                                                    ^
  symbol: variable Snackbar
packages/apps/ClubInternetLives/app/src/main/java/clubinternetlives/androidstudio/com/clubinternetlives/MainActivity.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                ^
  symbol: variable Snackbar
packages/apps/ClubInternetLives/app/src/main/java/clubinternetlives/androidstudio/com/clubinternetlives/MainActivity.java:14: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
packages/apps/ClubInternetLives/app/src/main/java/clubinternetlives/androidstudio/com/clubinternetlives/MainActivity.java:34: error: cannot find symbol
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        ^
  symbol:   method getMenuInflater()
  location: class MainActivity
packages/apps/ClubInternetLives/app/src/main/java/clubinternetlives/androidstudio/com/clubinternetlives/MainActivity.java:31: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
packages/apps/ClubInternetLives/app/src/main/java/clubinternetlives/androidstudio/com/clubinternetlives/MainActivity.java:50: error: cannot find symbol
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
               ^
  symbol:   variable super
  location: class MainActivity
packages/apps/ClubInternetLives/app/src/main/java/clubinternetlives/androidstudio/com/clubinternetlives/MainActivity.java:38: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
packages/apps/ClubInternetLives/app/src/test/java/clubinternetlives/androidstudio/com/clubinternetlives/ExampleUnitTest.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
        assertEquals(4, 2 + 2);
        ^
  symbol:   method assertEquals(int,int)
  location: class ExampleUnitTest
26 errors
make: *** [out/target/common/obj/APPS/ClubInternetLives_intermediates/classes-full-debug.jar] Error 41
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
ProGuard, version 4.10
Reading program jar [/Volumes/untitled/WORKING_DIRECTORY/out/target/common/obj/APPS/LiveWallpapers_intermediates/classes.jar]
Reading library jar [/Volumes/untitled/WORKING_DIRECTORY/out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/core-junit_intermediates/classes.jar]
Reading library jar [/Volumes/untitled/WORKING_DIRECTORY/out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/core-libart_intermediates/classes.jar]
Reading library jar [/Volumes/untitled/WORKING_DIRECTORY/out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/ext_intermediates/classes.jar]
Reading library jar [/Volumes/untitled/WORKING_DIRECTORY/out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/framework_intermediates/classes.jar]
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Preparing output jar [/Volumes/untitled/WORKING_DIRECTORY/out/target/common/obj/APPS/LiveWallpapers_intermediates/proguard.classes.jar]
  Copying resources from program jar [/Volumes/untitled/WORKING_DIRECTORY/out/target/common/obj/APPS/LiveWallpapers_intermediates/classes.jar]

#### make failed to build some targets (01:41 (mm:ss)) ####
```

The app compiles and runs on android studio without any errors and warnings. As far as the ROM setup is concerned, I have added the app name in **core.mk** file at build/target/product. I have also added an Android.mk file in the main folder of the app. Any idea what could be the reason for these errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was getting this error because my app had the precompiled java code that was created by Android studio. These errors were gone after I deleted those precompiled files from the java folder. The ROM compiler has a different build environment than the Android Studio or Eclipse environment.